# Implementing custom popup menul IntelliSense support on visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, visual-studio-extensions

Is it possible to customize the IntelliSense support on visual studio with customized pop up menu. i.e I want to have kind of parent menus for class names, so when user click on that class name it will show all the methods and members.

i.e when I type a dot char on VS it should display following kind of a menu.

```
Class1
Class2
```

Then When I click on 'Class1' parent menu item it should show child menu items.

```
Class1
    method1
    method2
Class2
```

Comment: It's deffinitly *possible*, both DevExpress' Refactor and the ReSharper extensions change how the intellisense popup works, but I don't know how they do it.

Comment: Those extensions simply reimplement the entire stack from scratch, which is probably not what lasithc wants to do.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski yes you are correct. I don't want to  reimplement the entire stack from scratch. Any idea other than this?